# how to prepend a string before a substring in T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql

If I have the following varchar:

```
SET @certificate = 'Custom_Birth-Certificates'
```

and I want to prepend the string '_CA' before the 
-Certificates string by identifying the -Certificates string within the whole string, so the result string is for example 'Custom_Birth_CA-Certificates' ( the _CA string is prepend before -Certificates ),

so in a few words I want to identify the -Certificates word within the string an prepend another string.

How can I achieve that in T-SQL ?

Comment: Always the same string, "-Certificates"?

Comment: Yes, the "-Certificates" string wont change, its always at the end of the string

Comment: There seems to be a lot of homework on T-SQL String manipulation functions today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility, using [`REPLACE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx):

```
SET @certificate = REPLACE(@certificate, '-Certificates', '_CA' + '-Certificates')
```

This would replace all matches in the string.

Comment: Just curious about why `'_CA' + '-Certificates'` instead of just `'_CA-Certificates'`?

Comment: A little extra leading in the event that "_CA" is a variable, to show you can concatenate the argument inside the function call.

Answer (score 2):

```
set @certificate = stuff(@certificate,patindex('%-Certificates',@certificate),0,'_CA')
```

Comment: One difference between this and Tim's is that this only replaces the first instance.

Comment: It also only matches the one at the end of the string which is what the OP described.

Comment: Ah hadn't spotted that. I did wonder why `patindex` not `charindex` as well.